# List increment for redis

Tags: redis, distributed-computing, distributed, distributed-system

Say that I have a list in redis, and a distributed service on top, the idea is for the distributed system to write data into this list, which can then be queried by other hosts.

Given a list like so:

```
1,2,3,4,1
```

I want to be able to do operations like `increment the first element by 5` and `increment the second element by 2` to get the end resulting list of:

```
6,4,3,4,1
```

Since the service is distributed, I cannot just grab the list, and then do the computation by the service and then set, as two machines may try to add 1 to the list, but due to them grabbing the same list we will have a race condition.

I also cannot enforce consistent hashing by the upstream, as hotkeys may have high load and lead to data skew, so I need a solution that can be load balanced by round-robin or some other non hash based algorithm by the upstream.

How can I accomplish this with redis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following two commands to achieve your goal:

1. `LINDEX`: get the value of at the given index.
2. `LSET`: set the value at the given index with an increased value.

In order to make these two commands atomic, so that it works in a distributed env. You can wrap these two commands into a [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval/):

```
local key = KEYS[1]
local index = ARGV[1]
local incr = ARGV[2]

local val = redis.call('lindex', key, index)
if not val then return nil end

val = tostring(tonumber(val) + tonumber(incr))
redis.call('lset', key, index, tonumber(val) + incr)

return val
```

However, both `LINDEX` and `LSET` are slow commands (especially with a long list), i.e. O(N) operation. You might need to redesign your code with a more efficient data structure.

Comment: I can split the elements in the list to seperate keys, i.e. instead of one key corresponding to a list of 5 elements I have 5 keys each to one element, would that be a more efficient or less efficient design?

Comment: Does order matter? If not, then just store each value in a key and use INCR and DECR.

Comment: @Baiqing If the length of list is short, normally, it's not a problem. You can do some benchmark.

Comment: @for_stack my actual length is around 60, not sure if this is considered long. The difference here would be potentially making 60 write calls to redis, or one large atomic operation to the list